# Why SQL Server generates two statements for only one foreign key?

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Let's say I have two tables:

- Foo (Id int, BarId int)
- Bar (id int, BarName varchar(50))

In the database diagram, I created a relationship between `Foo` and `Bar` and save changes.

The question: when I script the created key, I found there are two SQL statements generated:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Foo_Bar] 
        FOREIGN KEY([BarId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bar] ([BarId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Foo] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Foo_Bar]
GO
```

I wonder what the need of second statement is - isn't the first one enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder what the need of second statement is - isn't the first one
>   enough?

You are right, first one is enough for enabling the foreign key constraint. **Second statement is definitely is redundant in this case.**

SSMS might be using some generic templates for generating the script.

The main reason I feel behind this generation is to first create the constraint and enable it separately.